# Blender video editor - why can't I see my tracks?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I'm editing a video, and I was moving one of my .png images using a transform effect strip when all of my tracks apart from the text layers disappeared from the preview? I think I may have hit something when I went to insert a keyframe, but I'm not sure since I'm still pretty new to the software...

Here's what it currently looks like (some info like file names blanked out since its kinda a secret project for now...)

[image]
![][2]

So frustrating because its the second time its happened, so any thoughts?? :)

[EDIT] Thought I should mention; this is the whole way through the video.

[EDIT] Properties for the text layer

[image]
![][1]

Comment: Post a picture of the settings for that strip (I guess it would be the "You can't change this" png.)

Comment: Added the image :)